# HTMLAgilityPack reading values from screen

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get the value of a timer using the HtmlAgilityPack however when I get the innerText by the element ID it returns --:--:--

Is there any way to get the time value since it uses AJAX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using HtmlAgilityPack you can read only those values that rendered in the final HTML. if the timer is created by javascript or AJAX it's not possible to read it using this library cause that information is not exists in the rendered HTML

If you need to read the timer loaded by ajax try to find the service it calls you can use Firebug to find out

Hope it helps